# How to I create a hidden directory remotely through a script?

Tags: bash, scripts

Here is the body of the script I am running...

```
for i in `cat ${hostfile}`
        do
        echo "Adding user $username on $i"
        ssh -q $i /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/adduser $username --gecos "$username,,," --disabled-password;
        echo "$username:$password" | /usr/bin/sudo chpasswd;
        /usr/bin/sudo mkdir -p /home/$username/.ssh;
        /usr/bin/sudo touch /home/$username/.ssh/authorized_keys;
        /usr/bin/sudo chmod 600 /home/$username/.ssh/authorized_keys;
        /usr/bin/sudo chmod 700 /home/$username/.ssh;
        /usr/bin/sudo chown -R $username:$username /home/$username
        #ssh -q $i /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/adduser $username --gecos "$username,,," --disabled-password; sudo echo $username:'$password' | chpasswd; /usr/bin/sudo mkdir /home/$username/.ssh; /usr/bin/sudo touch /home/$username/.ssh/authorized_keys; /usr/bin/sudo chmod 600 /home/$username/.ssh/authorized_keys; /usr/bin/sudo chmod 700 /home/$username/.ssh; /usr/bin/sudo chown -R $username:$username /home/$username; adduser $username $group
done
```

It executes but does not create the .ssh directory.

Comment: Are the lines starting with `echo ` supposed to be run locally? What is the use of `;` at the end of lines?

Comment: As a general rule, it is safer to avoid `for i in $(cat file)` and use `while IFS= read -r file; do ...; done < file` which also avoids the unnecessary use of `cat`. See  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor. Granted, this shouldn't be an issue if your file is just a list of host names, but it's better to not get into this habit.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is only running *one* command on the remote server:

```
ssh -q $i /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/adduser $username --gecos "$username,,," --disabled-password;
```

Everything after that is run on your local machine instead. If you want to run multiple commands on the same `ssh` session, you need to pass them to `ssh` as a single command. For example:

```
while IFS= read -r  host; do
    echo "Adding user $username on $i"
    ssh -q "$host" "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/adduser '$username' --gecos '$username,,,' --disabled-password; \
    echo '$username:$password' | /usr/bin/sudo chpasswd; \
    /usr/bin/sudo mkdir -p /home/'$username'/.ssh; \
    /usr/bin/sudo touch /home/'$username'/.ssh/authorized_keys; \
    /usr/bin/sudo chmod 600 /home/'$username'/.ssh/authorized_keys; \
    /usr/bin/sudo chmod 700 /home/'$username'/.ssh; \
    /usr/bin/sudo chown -R '$username:$username' /home/'$username'"           
done < "$hostfile"
```

Note how all the commands are within the same `" "` quoted block. The `\` at the end of the line is just for clarity: they let you add the next command on a separate line.

Comment: Thank you very much terdon, this was a great explanation.  It worked like a charm!